# Compiler accuses "Error C2065: 'ENOTEMPTY': undeclared identifier". VS looks for its definition in WinSock.h instead of errno.h

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, compiler-errors

Working under Visual Studio 2010, I've developed a library to p/Invoke some stuff from a third-party native C++ dll. I haven't touched the C++ project in this solution for a while (even though I come back to the C# project every now and then) and everything was working fine. This morning I had to add a new method to the C++ project and I started getting the following error:

Error   2   error C2065: 'ENOTEMPTY' : undeclared identifier    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\system_error 40  1   xxxNativeDll

("xxxNativeDll" is my C++ wrapper to the third-party .dll)

I'm no expert in C++ but I poked around the web a bit and the closest clue I could find is in this post: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0abac212-6bde-40a0-81ce-9e2b0ddaa106/conversion-error-while-converting-project-from-msvs-2008-to-msvs-2010?forum=vcgeneral

Basically someone was getting the undeclared identifier error to all the macros in system_error and in the answer, he was told these macros are defined in errno.h. Well, here are my includes in the build output, from system_error up to the error itself:

2>  Note: including file:         C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\system_error

2>  Note: including file:          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cerrno

2>  Note: including file:           C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\errno.h

2>  Note: including file:            C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\crtdefs.h

2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\system_error(40): error C2065: 'ENOTEMPTY' : undeclared identifier

Just to be sure, I highlighted ENOTEMPTY, hit F12 (go to definition) and alas! I was redirected to WinSock.h in the C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Include folder. Surprisingly enough, only ENOTEMPTY redirects to this file, all other macros in system_error redirect to errno.h. I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the fact that I've installed WinDDK 7 a while back, but since I didn't need to rebuild the C++ project in this solution in a long time, there have been no errors since then.

So, long story short, VS "thinks" ENOTEMPTY from system_error is defined in WinSock.h while it should look for its definition in errno.h. Like I said, I'm no C++ pro, so how can I fix it? Please, I don't wanna add WinSock.h to my includes but I want VS to look for ENOTEMPTY in the correct file.

Comment: `ENOTMEPTY`? Don't you mean `ENOTEMPTY`?

Comment: Hmm, no, there is a `#if 0` directive before that declaration in Winsock.h.  Which you should never use btw, it was only meant to help port code that was written 25 years ago.  Go look in errno.h to see what happened to ENOTEMPTY, actually open the file.

Comment: I checked my `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\errno.h` file, and it has the definition for ENOTEMPTY (`#define ENOTEMPTY 41`).  My v7.0A WinSock.h has a place to define that, but it is in a `#if 0` block and hence not compiled.

Comment: Both of you are right. In my case, I have `#define ENOT       41` in errno.h but I have no idea how that happened. Should I just correct the header file? I would probably work but now I'm afraid of what caused it and what else could've happened...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, it had nothing to do with WinSock.h but rather a faulty errno.h file. I was gonna delete this question but decided to let it live as there's not enough information on these kind of problems out there.